# How to get a constant expression after exit of switch()?

Tags: c++

```
do{
      cin>>lim;
      switch(lim)
      {
      case 1: {const int limit=1; }break;
      case 2: {const int limit=2; }break;
      case 3: {const int limit=3; }break;
      case 4: {const int limit=4; }break;
      case 5: {const int limit=5; }break;
      case 6: {const int limit=6; }break;
      case 7: {const int limit=7; }break;
      case 8: {const int limit=8; }break;
      case 9: {const int limit=9; }break;
      case 10: {const int limit=10; }break;
      default: cout<<"Incorrect number, please repeat\n";
      }
 }while(lim<1 || lim>10);
mpa<limit,int,const char*> C;
```

I need to pass a constant value to the template. Constant is need to be initialized immediately. But it is destroyed after switch. How to correct it?

Comment: Nothing derived from run-time input is going to give you a constant expression that you can use as an argument to a template. You need to figure out a different approach (e.g., instantiate all 10 variations of the template and select the correct instantiation based on the run-time input).

Comment: I can't because object C wiil be destroyed after exit of switch

Comment: Declare 10 objects before the switch, and use the switch to choose one to return or assign.

Comment: @user1290126: you did not quite understand the comment: you cannot create that constant and use it to instantiate the template. The constant depends on runtime values, but instantiation must happen at compile time. You can, on the other hand, instantiate all versions and pick one: `case 1: mpa<1,int,const char*> C;`. Now the issue is how to get `C` out of the loop... simple answer, move everything other than the switch to a template function and call it: `case 1: process<1>();`, where process instantiates `mpa<...>`

Comment: @alexis: Not that simple: different instantiations are unrelated types, which means that you cannot *set a pointer* or something alike unless there is a base for all instantiations...

Comment: Right.. I was assuming that the templates are suitably designed, but they're probably not. The real solution is for @user to switch to a dynamically typed language...

Comment: Seriously, templates are not suitable for dynamic use. Design a (single) type that accepts a `limit` parameter in its constructor, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is impossible. The template is generated at compile-time while you want to give it a parameter that is determined at runtime. It's logically impossible.

What you should do is to change the definition of your template `mpa` to get the first parameter as a mandatory argument to its constructors (and of course dynamically allocate any memory based on that value).

Comment: This allows the constant to be declared outside of the switch, but does not solve the issue of the template instantiation (i.e. it will fail to compile the last line of the code).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, like I said in previous comment, I had misunderstood the question. I have updated the answer.